# Do autonomous transactions have their own session in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, session, transactions, distributed

I have a problem which may be due to distributed transactions. In the manual it says:

> When the first insert, update, or delete operation on a spatial table
> (one with a spatial index) is performed in a distributed transaction,
> all subsequent insert, update, or delete operations on the table, as
> well as any prepare to commit operation (the first branch to prepare a
> commit), in the transaction should happen in the same session as the
> first operation.

Since I'm doing autonomous transactions, I'm wondering if they happen in the same session or if a separate one is opened for them.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Insert the value of `sys_context('USERENV', 'SID')` into some table and check the value if it differs from main session or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session can have multiple transactions, so this is all done within a single session.

```
SQL> create table t ( n number);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p1 is
  3      pragma autonomous_transaction;
  4  begin
  5      insert into t values ( sys_context('userenv','sid'));
  6      commit;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p2 is
  3      pragma autonomous_transaction;
  4  begin
  5      insert into t values ( sys_context('userenv','sid'));
  6      commit;
  7      p1;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p3 is
  3      pragma autonomous_transaction;
  4  begin
  5      insert into t values ( sys_context('userenv','sid'));
  6      commit;
  7      p2;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec p3;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t;

         N
----------
       982
       982
       982
```